# Unit test RabbitMQ push with C# - .Net Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq

I have created a .net core API, which pushes a message in RabbitMQ queue. I have used `IOptions` to read configuration data from *.json* file and added it as dependency.

Below is the code of my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class RestController : Controller
{
    private RabbitMQConnectionDetail _connectionDetail;

    public RestController(IOptions<RabbitMQConnectionDetail> connectionDetail)
    {
        _connectionDetail = connectionDetail.Value;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Push([FromBody] OrderItem orderItem)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var rabbitMQConnection = new RabbitMQConnection(_connectionDetail.HostName,
                _connectionDetail.UserName, _connectionDetail.Password))
            {
                using (var connection = rabbitMQConnection.CreateConnection())
                {
                    var model = connection.CreateModel();
                    var helper = new RabbitMQHelper(model, "Topic_Exchange");
                    helper.PushMessageIntoQueue(orderItem.Serialize(), "Order_Queue");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        return Ok();
    }
 }
```

Connection details class has the below properties

```
public class RabbitMQConnectionDetail
{
    public string HostName { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to unit test it, but since I am going to test it against a blackbox, I'm not able to think of how to unit test it and looking for kind help.

ConnectionClass

```
public class RabbitMQConnection : IDisposable
{   
    private static IConnection _connection;
    private readonly string _hostName;
    private readonly string _userName;
    private readonly string _password;

    public RabbitMQConnection(string hostName, string userName, string password)
    {
        _hostName = hostName;
        _userName = userName;
        _password = password;
    }

    public IConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        var _factory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            HostName = _hostName,
            UserName = _userName,
            Password = _password
        };
        _connection = _factory.CreateConnection();
        var model = _connection.CreateModel();

        return _connection;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _connection.Close();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }
    }

    ~ RabbitMQConnection()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Helper class

```
public class RabbitMQHelper
{
    private static IModel _model;
    private static string _exchangeName;
    const string RoutingKey = "dummy-key.";

    public RabbitMQHelper(IModel model, string exchangeName)
    {
        _model = model;
        _exchangeName = exchangeName;
    }


    public void SetupQueue(string queueName)
    {
        _model.ExchangeDeclare(_exchangeName, ExchangeType.Topic);
        _model.QueueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);
        _model.QueueBind(queueName, _exchangeName, RoutingKey);
    }

    public void PushMessageIntoQueue(byte[] message, string queue)
    {
        SetupQueue(queue);
        _model.BasicPublish(_exchangeName, RoutingKey, null, message);
    }

    public byte[] ReadMessageFromQueue(string queueName)
    {
        SetupQueue(queueName);
        byte[] message;
        var data = _model.BasicGet(queueName, false);
        message = data.Body;
        _model.BasicAck(data.DeliveryTag, false);
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kinds of assertions are you expecting to write in these tests?

Comment: Since I am testing against a blackbox, I am not sure which assertion is going to help me. IsEqual is definitely not going to help. But If I can show the message count increased or there is next action upon the insert, that may help.

Comment: You need to test that controller return correct `IActionResult` and then check that correct message was pushed into the queue.

Comment: @ParthoGanguly Abstractions, abstraction, abstraction. You are trying to test an implementation concern that would change this to an integration test. Encapsulate the implementation concerns behind abstractions that can be mocked so that you can unit test in isolation.

Comment: @ParthoGanguly what version of RabbitMQ are you using?

Comment: @Nkosi  - version 3.6.12

Comment: @ParthoGanguly I searched the repo and cannot find the following classes: `RabbitMQHelper`, `RabbitMQConnection`. Are these custom classes in your library?

Comment: @Nkosi - Have added those

Comment: @ParthoGanguly I provided some suggestions. I am curious though. What is the reasoning behind having the static connection and model in your custom classes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tightly coupling your Controller to implementation concerns are making it difficult to test your controller without side-effects. From the sample you provided you have shown that you are encapsulating the 3rd part API implementations and only exposing abstractions. Good. You however have not created an abstraction that would allow you to mock them when testing. I suggest a refactor of the `RabbitMQConnection` to allow for this.

First have your own backing abstraction.

```
public interface IRabbitMQConnectionFactory {
    IConnection CreateConnection();
}
```

And refactor `RabbitMQConnection` as follows

```
public class RabbitMQConnection : IRabbitMQConnectionFactory {
    private readonly RabbitMQConnectionDetail connectionDetails;

    public RabbitMQConnection(IOptions<RabbitMQConnectionDetail> connectionDetails) {
        this.connectionDetails = connectionDetails.Value;
    }

    public IConnection CreateConnection() {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory {
            HostName = connectionDetails.HostName,
            UserName = connectionDetails.UserName,
            Password = connectionDetails.Password
        };
        var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Take some time and review exactly what was done with this refactor. The `IOptions` was moved from the Controller to the factory and the `RabbitMQConnection` has also been simplified to do it's intended purpose. Creating a connection.

The Controller now would need to be refactored as well

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class RestController : Controller {
    private readonly IRabbitMQConnectionFactory factory;

    public RestController(IRabbitMQConnectionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Push([FromBody] OrderItem orderItem) {
        try {                
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection()) {
                var model = connection.CreateModel();
                var helper = new RabbitMQHelper(model, "Topic_Exchange");
                helper.PushMessageIntoQueue(orderItem.Serialize(), "Order_Queue");
                return Ok();
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            //TODO: Log error message
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Again note the simplification of the controller. This now allows the factory to be mocked and injected when testing and by extension allows the mocks to be used by the `RabbitMQHelper`. You can use your mocking framework of choice for dependencies or pure DI.

Comment: I will check and update the post. Thanks a lot for you pointers.

Comment: Modified the code, and it looks much better now. Mocking now is feasible. Also, no connection object and model object is available. That was not good to have

Comment: @ParthoGanguly glad to help.

Comment: How to pass connection details?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is a unit test scenario. If you want to to test with external component ie database or message queue then i suggest you do it as integration test.

What we do is to have a sand box environment with component SQL database and azure message bus. We have code to correctly set the state for this component ie seed the database  and clear the message bus. Then we run test on the environment and check the state of the database or message bus count etc.

Comment: No first you have to write unit tests that will be sure that a specific method is called with correct parameters, integration test is another level that should be tested